Cannot RDP to Ubuntu from macOS after waking up Ubuntu from suspend
Ubuntu 24.04
Using Ubuntu's default desktop sharing & remote control, System -> Desktop Sharing & Remote control.
Accessing Ubuntu using Microsoft RDP.
I can connect and it all works fine except when I suspend Ubuntu and wake it up then can't RDP. I've to reboot Ubuntu to get RDP working again.
How to fix it?
